# grouper() example in itertools

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie to python. when reading the python standard library reference, I got confused by the grouper() example in itertools recipes section.

I tried to put the sample codes in a small program like below:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
import copy

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    # print each string in args
    #c = copy.deepcopy(args)
    #for a in c:
    #    print(list(a))
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def main():
    print("this is our first test script file")
    g = grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x')
    # print each string in results
    #for s in g:
    #    print(list(s))

main()
```

If we remove the comment tags, it would produce the results like below:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
[]
[]
['A', 'B', 'C']
['D', 'E', 'F']
['G', 'x', 'x']
```

This doesn't look right to me, because the results of the args variable is:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
[]
[]
```

how could the zip_longest() call produce results like below?

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
['D', 'E', 'F']
['G', 'x', 'x']
```

It should be A,B,C,D,... because the second and third list in args are empty. Or did I miss something?

Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` and `zip_longest` are quite different from `deepcopy` when it comes to how they consume their arguments.

`grouper` works because `zip` and `zip_longest` take one element at a time from each argument. For example, consider this:

```
i1 = i2 = i3 = iter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
zip(i1, i2, i3)
```

Because `i1`, `i2`, and `i3` share the same iterator, advancing one also advances the others. `zip` does this:

1. Take an element from `i1`.
2. Take an element from `i2`.
3. Take an element from `i3`.
4. Yield a tuple of these elements.
5. Repeat from step 1.

For the example, something like this happens:

First iteration:

1. Take an element from `i1`. => `1`
2. Take an element from `i2`. => `2`
3. Take an element from `i3`. => `3`
4. Yield a tuple of these elements => `(1, 2, 3)`

Second iteration:

1. Take an element from `i1`. => `4`
2. Take an element from `i2`. => `5`
3. Take an element from `i3`. => `6`
4. Yield a tuple of these elements => `(4, 5, 6)`

Now, `deepcopy`, in this case, only copies the iterators. It doesn't consume them in any way. Your `for` loop does however consume them:

1. Take everything from `i1`. => `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, StopIteration raised`
2. Take everything from `i2`. => `StopIteration raised`
3. Take everything from `i3`. => `StopIteration raised`

Therefore, you get the result that you see.

Comment: The `deepcopy` isn't copying the data at all, it's just copying the iterators. After the copy, the new iterators are still valid (and still all reverences to a single iterator, `deepcopy`'s clever about keeping identity relationships working within the object it copies). It's the Questioner's loop code that consumes all the values by passing one of the iterator references to `list`.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for pointing that out, I will make an edit!

Comment: Tomothy32's answer makes sense to me. From the debug view, I can see that the three iterators in args point to the same one. that explains. thanks for pointing out that the for loop consumes the iterator. Really appreciate the post. :)

Comment: Thanks to Blckknght. Your comment is eye opening to me too.

Answer (score 0):

The normal zip function takes the shortest iterator and only zips together those values, if another list is longer, it just ignores those values.
 Below you can see that the second list was of length 4, but it ignores the last element
From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

> Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted.

```
print(list(zip([1,2,3],['A','B','C','D'])))
#[(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C')]
```

Whereas zip_longest takes the longest iterator.
Below you can see that the second list was of length 4, but `zip_longest` did not ignore it.
From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables. If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is exhausted. Equivalent to:

```
import itertools as it
print(list(it.zip_longest([1,2,3],['A','B','C','D'])))
#[(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (None, 'D')]
```

The `fillvalue` argument fills the missing values with a default value. for e.g. below I have `fillvalue='X'`

```
import itertools as it
print(list(it.zip_longest([1,2,3],['A','B','C','D'], fillvalue='X')))
#[(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), ('X', 'D')]
```

Comment: I think OP knows how `zip_longest` works; they are just confused about why `deepcopy` shows what it does.